# Raphael Shape not Showing on page

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have an svg element and I wanted it to be in raphael code so I used "http://www.readysetraphael.com" to convert it. But I cannot get it to show up on the browser, can anyone point me into the right direction?

http://jsfiddle.net/trp40Lbg/

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '500', '500'); 

var path_a = rsr.path('here is a bunch of numbers and letters');
 path_a.attr({fill: '#000','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'path_a'); var rsrGroups = [];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Raphael JavaScript looks fine. However you do need an HTML element for Raphael to draw in. In your JavaScript example, it's looking for an element with the ID `rsr`, like a DIV. If you add an HTML element to your Fiddle with that ID, it works.

[Here is an updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trp40Lbg/1/).